# align view to a scaled ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, alignment, adjustviewbounds

i have this problem frequently, and I refuse to believe that it can't be solved without creating a custom layout:

How do you align a view with an ImageView that get scaled to match it's parent bounds but keeps the aspect ratio ( scale type is anything but fitXY ). I was under the assumption that f you set adjustViewBounds to true, the view bounds get adjusted to match the actual size of the image ("Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable."). But that is not the case. And it doesn't make and difference if the image has to get scaled up or down to fit its bounds.

Take a look at this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/square" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout looks like this: [image]

As you can see the bounds do not get adjusted and the TextView is aligned to the incorrect bounds. I created a custom Layout to creates the proper bounds, but maybe I'm missing something and it should be possible using the standard layout features...

EDIT: to clarify: i'm looking for a way to align the TextView with the actual image. that is with the red square in the given example.

Comment: what happens when your try with android:background="@drawable/square"?

Comment: "How do you align a view with an ImageView", so what do you actually mean?

Comment: Your TextView is properly aligned as per your specification in xml -alignRight and alirnTop. Where and how do you want to align.

Comment: I want to align the textview with the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it's been three years and you probably figured this out long ago. But you were halfway there when you specified adjustviewBounds=true. You just needed to change the ImageView layout width and height to wrap_content at the same time.

Your TextView IS aligning to your ImageView just as you requested. If you were to give your ImageView a background color you would see that it occupies the same area as your TextView. It's just that the actual image is centered within the view as you requested.

And you can continue to use scaleType=fitCenter or centerInside depending upon what you want. Neither will crop or stretch the image and your TextView will remain aligned.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use - `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` on the `ImageView`?
The image will be cropped to cover the entire layout, but the aspect ratio will be maintained.

Comment: if you you specify centerCrop the image will not be scaled up if it is smaller than the parent container.